# Disable vault spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, vault, spring-vault

I have a spring boot project where I wanted to disable the vault conditionally.

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId> 
  <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version> 
</dependency>
```

The version I am using. How can I do that?

I have spring profile-based configurations in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what do you mean by "disable" but you can use `spring.cloud.vault.enabled` configuration to disable all Vault-related beans created by [VaultAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-vault/blob/main/spring-cloud-vault-config/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/vault/config/VaultAutoConfiguration.java#L66).

To disable [Key-Value Backend](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.backends.kv.versioned) that allows to load properties during the startup (bootstrap) phase you can use
`spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled`.